# How can I change the default Google location for Unity search in dash?

Tags: unity-dash

By default, the online search Unity on my Ubuntu 14.04 is google.com. This is not very useful for me. How can I change this to  google.de or google.co.uk?

I found no way to do so in system settings. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your hosts file will allow you to override the DNS for a domain, on that particular machine.

ping google.com to find the IP address it's resolving to

ping google.de or google.co.uk to find the IP address it's resolving to

make note of these.

edit /etc/hosts with your favorite editor

Your hosts file will need to have two entries added that will contain the IP address you want the site to resolve to and the address.

for instance where xx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the ip address of google.de or google.co.uk:

xx.xxx.xxx.xxx google.com

xx.xxx.xxx.xxx www.google.com

This should do the trick. You can undo this redirection by simply removing the lines you added.

source: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file

Comment: it works in a short way, when you changes the host file it only is part working if the lenz is change it reverts to search for .com , not .de or .co.uk. Also .com is not showing in the host file. Is there something I am missing? I write in the ping address as you say.

Comment: it still thinks it's looking at google.com, buy changing the hosts file as instructed, you are overriding the DNS for google.com and it is actually using the IP address that you provided in the hosts file.